# Set the src attribute of img tag from an array element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, src

I have an array

```
pics = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
```

I want want to be able to set the src attribute of an image to an array element like so:

```
<img src = pics[0]>
```

Problem is that html does not recognize that I am want the string element pic[0] not literally "pic[0]", so it throws an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you selecting the picture, can you post that javascript?

Comment: need more details, please post your code

Answer (score 3):

You can't use JavaScript in arbitrary HTML attributes. You need to modify the DOM to add them afterwards.

```
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.alt = "Suitable alternative text";
 img.src = pics[0];
 document.getElementById('someElement').appendChild(img);
```

Make sure the script runs after `someElement` exists so it doesn't error on the last line.

Comment: I don't know about that.. pretty sure if it has something taht can uniquely identify it.. `<img id="somelink" src="">` you can modify it by doing `document.getElementById('somelink').src = pics[0];`  - though i haven't tried it.

Comment: There is no sign of there being an *initial* value for the (mandatory) `src` that doesn't come from JS, so the entire element should be created with JS.

Comment: what do you mean by the script should run after someElement?

Comment: I said "after someElement exists". If you run it before the element exists, then it will get `null` when `document.getElementById('someElement')` and then error when it tries to `null.appendChild(img);`. You need to put the script after that element, or in a function that isn't called until that element exists.

Comment: it works, just need to fiddle with CSS to make the image actually show up. Now it doesnt throw an error, but its just an empty box